# Yes! Paaawk mmm

Tags: cipher, visual, rebus

Try to make sense of what you see below.

---

> M◓_◔z◔z◔a◓(_◔ + ,◓)
>
> M◓_◔z◔z◔a◓(_◔ + ,◓)
>
> ◠◔(u◓ + _◔)_◔◠◔(_◔ + >◓)a◓z◔
>
> P◓_◔z◔z◔a◓(_◔ + ,◓)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is:

> W I N N e r
>  W I N N e r
>  C h I C K e N
>  d I N N e r
>
>  A [phrase](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/winner-winner-chicken-dinner/) used to celebrate a victory (like solving a puzzle...).

To work this out:

> Note that this obscure message consists of pairs of characters - in each case, a letter or punctuation mark, followed by a circle either quarter or half shaded.
>
>  We need to interpret the circles as an **instruction to rotate the preceding character by a quarter/half turn**. Furthermore, where two such pairs appear in brackets separated by a '+' sign, these characters should be combined after rotation. In all cases, the result of the rotation (± combination) is **another letter**.
>
>  **Key:**
>  M◓ = W
>  _◔ = I
>  z◔ = N
>  a◓ = e
>  (_◔ + ,◓) = | + ' = r
>  ◠◔ = C
>  (u◓ + _◔) = n + I = h
>  (_◔ + >◓) = | + < = K
>  P◓ = d

As for the title:

> 'paaawk' resembles the noise a chicken makes, while 'mmm' suggests something tasty - together, this is our 'chicken dinner'!

Comment: Clever! Wow, upvote.

Comment: Great job! Everthing looks good. The "Yes!" was just there to express what a person might say when winning.